# External Related table Keys

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a very huge table that contains a self-relation
the Key to this relation is inside a separate table
eg

```
master_table(
  Id int identity, 
  DATA_FIELDS)


key_table(
  masterId int,
  relativeId int)
```

Both the fields of the `key_table` are in the `master_table`.

My question is how to select from the master all the related data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will generate, for all master, the relative list of children data (only Id)

```
select M.Id as [Master Id],D.Id as [Detail Id] from master_table M 
inner join key_table MKT on (MKT.masterId = M.Id)
inner join master_table D on (MKT.relativeId = D.Id)
```

add other fields (from master/detail) as you need.

Comment: Don't use single quotes for aliases. Use either double quotes `as "Master Id"` or brackets: `as [Master Id]`. Or aliases without spaces: `as Master_Id`

Comment: the multi join with the size of the data will be a very slow and daunting i am talking about a set of millions of records

Comment: Generated plan is not complex (just 3 index scan - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3468c/9/0)
I don't known any other way. Do you have right PK and indexes on tables? Maybe someone else can help you.

Comment: @bellabax It seems to be the only way I googled around for other method and found none